# Returning platform shakes before setting active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I am making 2D game on Unity and I have a problem with rendering and moving order.
I have a script making platform fall and disappear when player steps on it. Here is main parts of my script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name.Equals("Player") && player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().IsGrounded() && !platformMovingBack) 
    {
        Invoke ("DropPlatform", 1f);
    }
}

void DropPlatform()
{
    rb.isKinematic = false;
    Invoke("DestroyPlatform", 0.4f);
    Invoke ("GetPlatformBack", 1.4f);
    Invoke("ResurrectPlatform", 2f);
}

void GetPlatformBack()
{
    rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    platformMovingBack = true;
}

void DestroyPlatform()
{
    transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

void ResurrectPlatform()
{
    rb.isKinematic = true;
    transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
void Update()
{

    if (platformMovingBack)
    {
        transform.position = initialPosition;
        transform.rotation = initialRotation;
        platformMovingBack = false;
    }
}
```

But I have a problem. Even though platform is becoming active only after all executions, in  game I see platform shaking and moving up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rb.isKinematic = false;
```

This makes it so the platform will be affected by external forces. Leave it on all the time, if you need to move the platforms with it on there are plenty of other ways such as lerp.

Comment: I just want Player was able to jump when it starts moving down.